# customize css in sharepoint 2010 and apply this to all pages that group by used in those views

Tags: 2010, list-view, css, custom, view

i decide to customize group by views that i create them in sharepoint 2010.

[image: solve problem in rtl right to left languages like persian or arabic]

for example for solving a problem in count that show after each group in group by views:

i use this css:

```
<style type="text/css">
td.ms-gb > span{direction:ltr !important;}
</style>
```

i use this code in all items.

[image: css rtl ltr count problem group by sharepoint 2010]

what is the standard way to customize all views that have group by? and apply it to all of the inherited pages in a site collection?

Comment: Put the CSS in Master Page.. Or better put the css in a separate file (upload to Style Library/Layouts folder), link the CSS file in Master Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site has the publishing feature enabled, save the CSS in a custom CSS file, upload it to the Style Library of the site collection and then refer to it in the Alternate CSS URL that you can specify with Site Actions > Site Settings > Master Page.

If the site does not have the publishing feature enabled, upload the custom CSS file to the site collection Style Library, create a custom master page for the site (never change the original master page) and load the CSS in there.

Find the line `<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>` and put your custom CSS in the next line, like this:

```
    <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/Style Library/CSS/MyCustom.css" after="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

Your file name and exact location may differ, depending on whether or not you use managed paths.